# Is the empty set linearly independent or linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

Is the empty set linearly independent or dependent?

Comment: It is linearly independent because it cannot be linearly dependent (that is, you cannot write any element as a linear combination of other vectors). It is a bit vacuous though...

Comment: :) Similarly, what is the answer to "the empty question"? :)  More seriously, I hope you are not toooo seriously caught up in this nearly-purely-semantic question. :)

Comment: @copper.hat ... wait, can't I write _every_ (non-existent) element as a linear combination of the other (non-existent) elements, because the condition parses as being vacuous? Or maybe I'm just tired, and it's Friday. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett To be ld. there must exist vectors such that...

Comment: The empty set should be linearly independent because it is a basis for the zero vector space.

Comment: so, is $\{0\}$ a basis for $\{0\}$ ?

Answer (score 34):

By definition, it is linearly independent, because it is not *linearly dependent*.

A set $S$ is linearly dependent if there exists a finite set of vectors $v_1,\dots, v_n$ and corresponding scalars $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ such that there exists at least one $\alpha_i\neq0$ so that $$\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i=0$$

---

Remark: (equivalently, we could demand that **all** $\alpha_i$ are nonzero, but then we would also need to demand that there exists at least one $\alpha_i$ that is nonzero. This is because the empty set satisfies the demand that every element from it is nonzero...)

---

Clearly, these is no finite collections of vectors from $\{\}$ that satisfies the above condition, because there is no collection *at all*.

---

Furthermore, the empty set is also a *basis* of the vector subspace $\{0\}$, because $\{0\}$ is the

> Smallest vector space that includes $\{\}$ and is a vector space.

---

In a way, you could also round-about your reasoning that $\{\}$ is linearly independent like this:

- You know that $\{0\}$ is a vector space.
- You know that every vector space has a basis.
- You know that the basis of $\{0\}$ is a subset of $\{0\}$, so the basis of $\{0\}$ can either be $\{\}$ or $\{0\}$
- You know that $\{0\}$ is not a basis because it is not linearly independent (because $1\cdot 0=0$)
- Therefore, $\{\}$ is a basis.
- Because all bases are linearly independent, so is $\{\}$

Note, this isn't really a "good" proof because it makes a sort of begging the question fallacy. This wasn't meant to be a proof in a mathematical sense, just a proof "to yourself" that you *already know* the empty set is linearly independent, because that's the only way every vector space can have a basis, and you *know* that that is true (and, in fact, you or someone else must have used the fact that the empty set is linearly independent while proving that fact)

Comment: The empty set is finite, and the empty sum is often considered to be $0$. Should some of the scalars be nonzero? Because this will not be possible in case of the empty set...

Comment: @Servaes The definition calls for at least one vector in the sum, so it does not include the empty sum, otherwise **no** set is linearly independent.

Comment: Very true. Was just trying to point out that the definition of linear independence was poorly formulated in more than one respect.

Comment: You're missing a crucial point, a set is linearly dependent if there are scalars *not all zero* such that...

Comment: A definition of "(finite) linear combination" that excludes the case of zero terms is not a good definition of linear combination. e.g. every vector in a vector space can be written uniquely as a linear combination of basis elements... even when we consider the zero vector space.

Comment: Also, {} is an (empty) finite collection of vectors from {}.

Comment: What should have been edited in is not that the relevant sets of vectors and scalars must be nonempty but rather that (as @YoTengoUnLCD pointed out) at least one of the scalars must be nonzero.  That implies the nonemptiness requirement (because the empty set of scalars has no nonzero elements).

Comment: @EricWofsey It is sort-of-circular, that's what I meant by round-abouting. What I meant there was that the OP actually already knows that $\{\}$ is linearly independent, but that knowledge is packed up with some other facts into the sentence "Every vector space has a basis"

Comment: @user21820 The answer is not corrected because, believe it or not, I don't spend every moment of my life behind a computer. I am working hard on my correcting-MO-errors-while-I-am-asleep skills, but obviously, they need work. Maybe I should just set an alarm clock to wake me whenever I make a mistake on the internets...

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks, I fixed it! I was sloppy the first time around.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Thanks, fixed it!

Comment: @Hurkyl Yeah, it wasn't well written before, I think it's better now.

Comment: I thought (clearly mistakenly) that you would have noticed the error since Servaes' very first comment had a remark about it. But never mind it's ok now!

Comment: @user21820 I corrected the first comment's mistake, but introduced new ones which i then didn't fix until now :)

Comment: Ahh no wonder. Sorry about my hasty assumption.

Comment: Hello! May I ask you a question please? I am bit confused with your proof. Empty set should be linearly independent AND linearly dependent because they are vacuously true. Am I wrong?

Comment: @RFZ No. By your logic, every statement is true for the empty set.

Comment: @RFZ As I wrote, "A set $S$ is linearly dependent if there exists a finite set of vectors $v_1,\dots, v_n$ and corresponding scalars $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ such that there exists at least one $\alpha_i\neq0$ so that $$\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i=0$$". This statement is **not** true for the empty set. Therefore, the empty set is **not** linearly dependent (meaning that, by definition, it **is** linearly **in**dependent).

Comment: I apologize for the slight delay in responding to your comment. I've always believed that vacuously true means that any statement holds for an empty set. So it looks that I was wrong? Could you please clarify this for me?

Comment: @RFZ If any statement holds for the empty set, then does the statement "$X$ is not an empty set" hold if $X$ is the empty set?

Comment: @RFZ The empty set is not some magical thing that you can just apply any statement to. In fact, if $P(X)$ is any statement about sets $X$, then naturally, if $P(\emptyset)$ is **true**, then $\neg P(\emptyset)$, i.e., the negation of the statement, **must** be false.

Comment: @RFZ That said, the empty set has no **elements**, so any statement about the properties of the **elements** of an empty set will be true. For example, every element of an empty set is a positive integer. Also, every element of an empty set is a negative integer.

Comment: @RFZ Note that this is about the **properties** of the elemnents of the set. Not about the elements themselves. So, of course, it is **not** true that there exists an element of an empty set. In other words, any statement of the type "$\forall x\in\emptyset: P(x)$" will be true (because it is equivalent to $\forall x: x\in\emptyset \implies P(x)$), while every statement of the type "$\exists x\in\emptyset: P(x)$" is false (because it is equivalent to $\exists x: x\in\emptyset \land P(x)$). Both of these properties stem directly from the fact that $x\in\emptyset$ is always a false statement.

Comment: @5xum Thank you very much for your reply! I spent some time carefully reading it, and here is what I have.

**Definition:** A set of vectors $S=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is linearly dependent if there exists $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$, not all zero, such that $\lambda_1 x_1+\dots+\lambda_n x_n=0$. Equivalently, a set of vectors $S=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is linearly dependent if and only if there exists $x\in S$ such that $x$ is a linear combination of the remaining vectors.

Comment: @5xum Our goal is to show that $S=\varnothing$ is linearly independent. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $S=\varnothing$ is linearly dependent. Then, by the equivalent definition, $\exists x\in S$ such that $x$ is a linear combination of the remaining vectors. However, this is a contradiction because $S=\varnothing$. Hence, $S=\varnothing$ is linearly independent. Here, basically I've used the fact which you mentioned in your comment: the statement of the type $``\exists x\in \varnothing: P(x)"$ is false.

Comment: @5xum I understand that this might seem like a trivial question, but I had a mistaken understanding of vacuous truth. I believe that the proof above is correct. However, to be honest, I have a feeling that the definition of linearly dependent vectors implicitly assumes that $S$ should be nonempty. Is that the case, or not?

Comment: @RFZ "A set of vectors $S=\{x_1,\dots x_n\}$ is linearly dependent if there exists $λ_1,\dots,λ_n,$ not all zero, such that $λ_1x_1+⋯+λ_nx_n=0$." No, this is not a good definition. This definition only correctly covers **finite, non-empty** sets. This definition, for example, does not tell you if $\mathbb R$ is finite, because there is no $n$ such that $\mathbb R=\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$. Like I said, the definition of linearly dependent sets is what I already wrote in my answer.,

Comment: @RFZ The correct definition is that $S$ is linearly dependent if there exists some finite non-empty subset of $S$, say, $X=\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$, and a set of scalars $\{\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n\}$ not all zero, such that $\lambda_1x_1+\cdots+\lambda_n x_n=0$. For the empty set, there does not exist any non-empty subset of an empty subset, therefore, the empty set cannot be linearly dependent.

Comment: I apologize but I am confused with your definition. In your definition for some reason you assume that $S$ is arbitrary set but I believe it should be nonempty. For example, here is the definition of **linearly independent**. Let $V$ be a vector space. A nonempty set $S$ of vectors in $V$ is linearly independent if for any distinct vectors $s_1,\dots,s_n$ in $S$, $$a_1s_1+\dots+a_ns_n=0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad a_i=0\quad \text{for all}\ i$$. I think it is not possible to rigorously demonstrate that the empty set is linearly independent.

Comment: Instead, I believe it is conventionally considered to be linearly independent.

Comment: @RFZ No, $S$ does not need to be non-empty. The following statement is the definition of linearly dependent sets: "$X$ is linearly dependent **if and only if** there exists some *finite, non-empty subset $S=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\subseteq X$* and some finite collection of scalars $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$, such that (1) not all scalars equal $0$ and (2) $\alpha_1x_1+\cdots \alpha_n x_n = 0$".

Comment: @RFZ Under this definition, the rules of logic and logic alone dictate that the empty set is linearly independent, because the statement "$\emptyset$ is linearly dependent" **is a false statement**. It is a false statement because there does not exist any finite nonempty subset of $\emptyset$ with the required properties. You do not need to add anything into the definition, nor do you have to **define** the empty set to be linearly independent.

Comment: I am sorry but where did you get this definition? Can you tell me please? For example, the definition of linearly independent vectors which I wrote in my previous comment requires $S$ to be nonempty and hence for linearly dependent vectors $S$ should be nonempty as well. This is the definition from Steve Roman's book "Advanced Linear Algebra". P.S. I understand the logic behind your definition but I am bit confused where did you get this definition.

Comment: @RFZ My definition is straight up translated from the linear algebra textbook I used when studying. THe textbook is in slovenian :). The textbook you provide is very strange to me as it actually does not define whether the empty set is linearly independent or not. For example, it also says "Any vector space, except the zero space $\{0\}$, has a basis" which is a consequence of the strange definition.

Answer (score 13):

Since the correct definition of "linearly dependent" has not been spelled out in detail in any of the answers so far, let me add a new answer.  A subset $S$ of a vector space $V$ is defined to be linearly dependent if there exist finitely many distinct elements $s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n\in S$ and scalars $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n$ which are not all $0$ such that $$\sum_{i=1}^n c_is_i=0.$$

(If $S$ itself is finite, you can just state this condition with $s_1,\dots,s_n$ being all the elements of $S$, since given any relation of this form you can just make the coefficients be $0$ for all the elements of $S$ you have not used.)

When $S=\emptyset$, the only possible collection of finitely many distinct elements of $S$ is the empty collection, with $n=0$.  But there does not exist any collection of $0$ scalars, not all of which are $0$.  After all, if you have a collection of no scalars, then vacuously all the scalars in your collection are $0$.

Thus $\emptyset$ is linearly independent (as a subset of any vector space).

Comment: ``After all, if you have a collection of no scalars, then vacuously all the scalars in your collection are 0.`` But there are no scalars , so how can you say all the scalars are 0.

Comment: This is just what "all" means in mathematics.  Look up "vacuous truth".

Comment: I believe in your definition of linearly dependent the subset $S\subset V$ should be nonempty.

Answer (score 11):

It is linearly independent.

If a set is linearly dependent, then there would be a nontrivial linear combination of the vectors in the family that added up to the zero vector. It is also impossible to choose a vector in the empty set and write it as a linear combination of the other vectors in the empty set, since the empty family is empty.

Answer (score 7):

Not only is it linearly independent, but it is also the basis for $\{\textbf{0}\}$.

Comment: Yep! Furthermore, $\{\mathbf{0}\}$ *fails* to be linearly independent.

Comment: Well, the fact that it is a basis for *some* space shouldn't be that surprising, since every linearly independent set is a basis for its span...

Answer (score 2):

The explainations offered above focus largely on showing the empty set is NOT linearly dependent and therefore must be linearly independent. I find this somewhat unsatisfying, so I attempt a more direct proof that the empty set is linearly independent...

Recall that any subset $V = \{ v_1, v_2, ..., v_n \}$ of some vector space $\mathbb{V}$ is a linearly independent set iff the trivial solution is the $only$ solution to $\sum_{j=1}^n c_j v_j = \bf 0$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$; $\bf 0$ is the zero vector; and $c_j$ is a scalar for $j=1,2,...,n$. To be more precise, $V$ is a linearly independent set iff the above equation is satisfied by $exactly$ $one$ set of $n$ scalars $S = \{ c_1, c_2,..., c_n \}$ such that, for every $i\in I = \{ 1,2,...,n \}$, we have $c_i = 0$ where $I$ is an index set. Thus, in order to prove some set $V$ is a linearly independent set, we must prove the following two conditional statements:

**1st conditional statement:**

$ \forall i \Big [ i \in I \to c_i = 0 \Big ] \Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^n c_j v_j = \bf 0 $

**2nd conditional statement:**

$ \sum_{j=1}^n c_j v_j = {\bf 0} \Rightarrow \forall i \Big [ i \in I \to c_i = 0 \Big ] $

Now we prove the empty set $\emptyset$ consisting of $n=0$ vectors is a linearly independent set. Of course, since $n=0$, the sequence of $n$ vectors $v_1, v_2, ..., v_n$ in $V$ reduces to an empty sequence, implying $V=\emptyset$. The same is true of the sequence of $n$ scalars in $S$ as well as the sequence of $n$ indices in the index set $I$, implying $S=\emptyset$ and $I=\emptyset$.

We prove the 1st conditional statement as follows: by substitution, we may rewrite the antecedant as $\forall i \Big [ i \in \emptyset \to c_i = 0 \Big ]$. Note that $i\in \emptyset$ is always false because the empty set has no members. Hence, the antecedant is a vacuously true statement. With respect to the consequent, by substitution we may rewrite it as $\sum_{j=1}^0 c_j v_j = \bf 0$. Note that $\sum_{j=1}^0 c_j v_j$ is an empty (or nullary) sum equal to the additive identity element of the vector space, which in this case is the zero vector $\bf 0$. Hence, the consequent reduces to ${\bf 0} = \bf 0$, which is of course true. Since the antecedant and consequent are true, the 1st conditional statement must be true.

By the same reasoning, we can show the 2nd conditional statement is true. In this case, the antecedant reduces to ${\bf 0} = \bf 0$, which is true, and the consequent is vacuously true.

Since the 1st and 2nd conditional statements are true, we have shown that $V=\emptyset$ is a linearly independent set.

Answer (score 1):

Belatedly, there might be some silly-but-not-worthless point to be made here, about mathematical conventions. Certainly we grant that everyone here knows full well what an empty set of vectors is. :)

A slightly interesting question is about what *we_intend* (not so much "the definition"...) by "linearly independent set of vectors". For example, operationally (as opposed to definitionally), for example, we'd mean that the set cannot be shrunk without shrinking the span. Or, equivalently, "for all vectors $v$ in the set, $v$ is not expressible as a linear combination of any of the other vectors in the set". Yes, there are other linguistic variants on the definition.

But, if we choose the above-mentioned course: since the span of $\phi$ is
$\{0\}$ (oop, we need to specify what the span of the empty set is... in a given vector space?!?!?!) ... this subspace cannot be shrunk, so the vectors "spanning" it are linearly independent.

And/or, the "for all $v$ in the set ..." condition is vacuous for the empty set of vectors.

So, although it has essentially no mathematical content, there are indeed arguments in favor of declaring that the empty set of vectors is linearly independent. :)

Answer (score 0):

The empty set is linearly independent. If you are familiar with basic mathematical logic, you will find the argument below very easy to understand.

> **Definition:** Let $\mathcal B$ be a subset of a vector space $V$.
>
> (a) $\mathcal B$ is said to be a **linearly dependent set** if there exists a vector $v\in \mathcal B$ such that
> $v\in\operatorname{span}\left[\mathcal B\setminus \{v\}\right]$. In other words, $\mathcal B$ is said to be a **linearly dependent set** if $\exists v\left(v\in\mathcal B \land v\in\operatorname{span}\left[\mathcal B\setminus\{v\}\right]\right)$.
>
> (b) $\mathcal B$ is said to be **linearly independent** if $\mathcal B$ is not linearly dependent.

**Theorem:** The empty set $\varnothing$ is linearly independent.

*Proof.* We have to prove that $\lnot\exists v\left(v\in \varnothing \land v\in\operatorname{span}\left[\varnothing\setminus\{v\}\right]\right)$ is true. Equivalently, we have to prove that $\forall v\left(v\in \varnothing \implies v\notin\operatorname{span}\left[\varnothing\setminus\{v\}\right]\right)$ is true. Since the antecedent $v\in\varnothing$ is false for all $v$ (the empty set $\varnothing$ has no elements), then $\forall v\left(v\in \varnothing \implies v\notin\operatorname{span}\left\{\varnothing\setminus\{v\}\right\}\right)$ is (vacuously) true. Therefore, the empty set $\varnothing$ is linearly independent.