# Set theory and subspace definition do not add up.

Tags: vector-spaces

In class today,  we talked about vector subspaces.

A subspace $v$ of a vector space $V$ (for this instance,  $V$ is $\mathbb R^3$) is a space which all values of $v$ are within $V$, and some vector within $V$ can be added to $v$ to get another specific vector which is contained within $V$, thus every vector in $V$ can be made by summing some multiples of vectors within $v$

Say that $v$ is $\{[1\;0\;0],[0\;1\;0],[0\;0\;1]\}$, the column vectors of $Id_3$.

My professor said that the empty set $\emptyset = \{\}$ is within any set that spans $\mathbb R^3$.

This means that there is a sum of multiplies of the vectors within v that is equal to $\emptyset$, correct?  Why or why not?

Comment: The empty set $\emptyset$ is a subset of **any** set. For a vector space, we also have the set containing the zero vector is contained in the vector space, that is $\{0\} \subset V$. However, these are two completely different things.

Comment: If your professor really did use $v$ for the name of a subspace of a vector space $V$, then it's no wonder you're confused. I would be too.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein i couldn't figure out how to serif the V.

Comment: Your main paragraph (the second one) in a single sentence describes **three** different things (and the middle one doesn't even make much sense). Could you please explain more clearly what exactly you're talking about and what exactly you're asking?

Comment: @zipirovich i wish that i could.  Maybe if you tell me what 3 things I'm referring to,  i could.

Comment: v is not a subspace it's just a set that spans V (a basis for V)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I3 is the 3x3 identity matrix.

Comment: and also empty set is not in every set that spans V. it's so not correct

Comment: @Parto why not?

Comment: @tuskiomi :"My professor said that the empty set is within any set that spans R3". It means that empty set is within every basis of R3. it's not correct so maybe edit your post.

Comment: @tuskiomithe correct sentence would be empty set is in the set of all subsets of a set.

Comment: @parto but that's one of the properties of the empty set, that it's a subset of every set, thus there is a null element in every set.

Comment: @tuskiomi Note that a *subset* of a set is not the same thing as an *element* of a set. For example, $\emptyset$ is a subset of the set $\{1\}$, but it is not an element of $\{1\}$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein as far as I see,$\{\}$ doesn't occur in $\{1\}$, either.

Comment: Can you find an element of $\{\}$ which is not an element of $\{1\}$? If you can't, then it's a subset.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein the element "" is not a part of the list.

Comment: @tuskiomi The intended meaning of $\{\}$ is a set which has *no* elements. It seems you're reading that it does contain an element, namely the empty string. That is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The empty set is a **subset, not a member** of every such set. Only if the empty set were a **member** of the span of a set of vectors would it be a sum of scalar multiples of those vectors. The empty set is not a vector, so it's not a sum of scalar multiples of any vectors.

Answer (score 1):

I think there may have been some missing information in what your professor told you.

From a set theory standpoint, if $U$ is any subspace of a vector space $V$ then  $\emptyset \subset U \subseteq V.$ Now, you might wonder what role $\emptyset$ plays in the language of linear algebra.

The trivial subspace $\{0\}$ is a subspace of every vector space,  which you can verify axiomatically that it satisfies all of the conditions of a subspace. You might also recognize that $\emptyset$ is a basis for $\{0\}/$ and so $\{0\}$ is a subspace of any vector space because its basis, namely $\emptyset,$ is subset of every basis, for any vector space.

Comment: It is not true that $\emptyset$ is a basis for $\{0\}$.

Comment: @copper.hat seriously? Even if you have some gripes with empty sums or something, you have to acknowledge that plenty of mathematicians agree that the empty set is a basis for $\{0\}$.

Comment: @copper.hat, Would you care to explain why it is not a basis?

Comment: There are many resources which agree with my assertion being correct. I'm happy to change it if you have a resource which disagrees with my assertion. Example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909645/empty-set-is-the-only-basis-of-the-zero-vector-space-0

Comment: How can I choose vectors in $\emptyset$ such that $0$ is a linear combination of those non existent vectors?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: I realise that it is a convention that many use, but in context I think it very confusing for the OP.